# Case sensitive string comparison in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-comparison

The following code:

```
if "IAMBIG" > "iambig":
      print("True")
else:
      print("False")
```

results in:

```
False
```

Since Python is case-sensitive, I understand that checking for equality would result in `False` in the above `if` statement. However, I am not sure how `string` comparison works when checking for - "greater than" (or less than) condition.

Can anybody explain why I am getting `False` in the above `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 compares strings as sequences of unicode characters. Since the unicode number for character `I` is `U+0049` and for character `i` is `U+0069`, it is natural that the comparison `"I..." > "i..."` returns `False`.

I general latin small letters have numbers larger than large letters, which will  make capitalized strings "smaller" than lowercase when using comparison operators.

For reference, here's a link to the basic latin unicode block: http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/basic-latin/